# can i invoke a program on linux through selenium automation script?

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am trying to automate the execution of a word count program through selenium ide, which actualy will run on Linux machine.(selenium on windows and wordcount on linux).
is it possible with selenium ide, or any other tool?

Answer (score 1):

we don't know your wordcount application. As far it is a web application which can be accessed via firefox browser you can use the Selenium IDE. If you provide a link to your application I can tell you more about the possibility.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but it isnt a web application, jst a program which will be running on linux server, and i can only see whether the program is successfully run or not through browser.

Comment: then you can only automate the validation if the program ran successful or not. you can't automate a native program with selenium.